# How to say "about" as in about page

Tags: vocabulario

I have a simple webpage, [La ComeBotella](http://www.edibottle.netau.net) that I'm using for a Spanish project.

I'm trying to translate the initial English version I debuted with, and I was wondering how to say "about" when talking about a page that has extra information. I tried searching around a little bit but none were the same situations.

I guess I could use "Sobre la ComeBotella" but that would be too long. I could also use "Información" but it feels long too.

Is there a short and simple way to say "about" in this situation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply "**Acerca de**" is common usage in the wild, without need for it to be the complete "Acerca de La ComeBotella".

Answer (score 7):

In the web is common the use of:

- Acerca de `<`La ComeBotella`>`
- ¿Quiénes somos? **<<== Most common**
- Sobre Nosotros

Answer (score 2):

Also note that in most of Computational Software, "About" is translated as "Acerca de..." (Next to Help to show information about the software itself). I saw this by the first time in Windows 95. Now, all softwares translate in this way.